# Creating unique rows of SKUs on Excel from single rows

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-formula

I have a lot of rows of data in Excel, each one corresponds to a product. So for example, my first row is "Lady's Black Dress" and then it has in another cell, sizes separated by commas and also colours in one cell too.

```
Title           Size          Colour                 Price Before  Price After
Ladies Dress    S,M,L,XL,XXL  Blue, Black, Red       19.99          29.99
Men's Trousers  S,M,L,XL,XXL  Brown, Yellow, Orange  39.99          59.99
```

hj 
[image: Data now]

So what I need is a VBA that creates a unique row (SKU, essentially) for each product variaton, so my data then looks like this:

[image]

I did ask this question before but only for 2 columns, a kind soul provided this VBA which does work, but I need the other columns. I don't quite understand how to adapt this VBA and was changing the letter "B" to "E" but this doesn't seem to work.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sizeExpansion()
    Dim i As Long, szs As Variant

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            szs = Split(.Cells(i, "B").Value2, ",")
            If CBool(UBound(szs)) Then
                .Cells(i, "A").Resize(UBound(szs), 1).EntireRow.Insert
                .Cells(i, "A").Resize(UBound(szs) + 1, 1) = .Cells(UBound(szs) + i, "A").Value2
                .Cells(i, "B").Resize(UBound(szs) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(szs)
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this modification with an additional split variant and some maths adjustment.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sizeAndColorExpansion()
    Dim i As Long, s As Long, c As Long
    Dim ttl As String, pb As Double, pa As Double
    Dim szs As Variant, clr As Variant

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            ttl = .Cells(i, "A").Value2
            pb = .Cells(i, "D").Value2
            pa = .Cells(i, "E").Value2
            szs = Split(.Cells(i, "B").Value2, ",")
            clr = Split(.Cells(i, "C").Value2, ",")
            If CBool(UBound(szs)) Or CBool(UBound(clr)) Then
                .Cells(i, "A").Resize((UBound(szs) + 1) * (UBound(clr) + 1) - 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
                For s = 0 To UBound(szs)
                    For c = 0 To UBound(clr)
                        .Cells(i + (s * (UBound(clr) + 1)) + c, "A").Resize(1, 5) = _
                            Array(ttl, Trim(szs(s)), Trim(clr(c)), pb, pa)
                    Next c
                Next s
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This places all the sizes correctly, but then creates another row to show the colour and doesn't copy the colours, just shows one entry in the correct column. The prices appear only once per group too, rather than copied down the whole group. Bit difficult to show that here!

Comment: Try it in a fresh workbook on the sample data above. Seems to work for me.

Comment: This works fine, thanks. In my real data I had some runtime errors: 1) I removed some commas from the end of some cells 2) I replaced any empty cells with text I could remove later - searched and replaced empty cells 3) Removed $ signs from the sell prices. Thanks, marvellous stuff!